# SignInAsync in MVC ASP.net (User roles)

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, account, user-roles

I got the following code working on my desktop. Currently I'm working on my laptop and this code just doesn't wanna work, it says that "SignInAsync" doesn't exist in the current context.

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

                var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    AddErrors(result);
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally there is a method in the controller:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() 
    { 
         IsPersistent = isPersistent 
    }, await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager));
}
```

If it's there you can call it. If it's not, I think you should add it.

Note; this should be part of the Identity template in the account controller. So perhaps you are using another template or are using this method from another controller.

My best guess is, that since your code is working on your desktop and not on your laptop, you didn't copied the whole project but just copied some part of the code, perhaps in a different templated setup.